# pass parameter in onclick function to php

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I've created dynamic links with an editName(id) function

```
<a onclick="{editName(2); $('#editName').dialog('open');}" 
style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">My Name</a>
```

In the above example My Name has an id=2

Now I can simply show an alert but **how can I echo id through PHP?**

```
function editName(id)
{
alert(id);
// <?php echo(id);?> 
}
```

Comment: `Java` != `JavaScript`. For more info read tag descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to assign javascript value to php untill and unless you give ajax call

So Create Hidden Value in Your HTML

```
<a onclick="{editName(2); $('#editName').dialog('open');}"
style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">My Name</a>
<input type="hidden" id="name_id" value="<?php echo $nameId?> " />

function editName(id)
{
alert(id);
var id1 =  $("#name_id").val();
alert(id1)
// <?php echo(id);?> 
}
```

Comment: alert(id) and alert(id1) give the same value, but how can I use 
    <?php echo(id1);?>
to echo the variables in PHP?